# Syslog max parameter size

Tags: regex, database, nlog, syslog

I'm configuring Syslog layout and I'm wondering if I can set a max string size for a parameter, so the output won't be to long. For example:

```
<parameter name="@tresc_requestu" layout="${event-context:item=tresc_requestu}" />
```

I would like the log output to be max 5 char long. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

NLog ver. 4.6.3 now supports truncate:

```
${event-context:item=tresc_requestu:truncate=5}
```

Older versions of NLog can use this very cryptic logic to truncate at 5 characters:

```
${trim-whitespace:inner=${event-context:item=tresc_requestu:padding=-5:fixedLength=true}}
```